# Set every pixel of a Mat to a certain value, if it´s lower than a value?

Tags: c++, opencv, threshold

Im trying to do the following in OpenCV. How can I set every pixel of a Mat to a certain value, if it´s lower than a value?

So I want to do something like the [threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762959/proper-thresholding-function-in-opencv-c), but not quite, as I don't want to touch pixels above the given threshold.

For example: Set every pixel to 50 which is smaller than 50.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: C++, Matlab, Python or Java ?

Comment: In C++, i tried set to, but actually I do not really know how i use such a certain mask :/

Answer (score 12):

Regarding your particular request:

> set to `50` all pixels `< 50`

using matrix expressions and `setTo` is straightforward:

```
Mat m = ...
m.setTo(50, m < 50);
```

---

In OpenCV, you compute can compute thresholds using [cv::threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html), or comparison [Matrix Expression](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat#matrix-expressions).

As you're probably already doing, you can set to `255` all values `> th` with:

```
double th = 100.0;
Mat m = ...
Mat thresh;
threshold(m, thresh, th, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
```

or:

```
double th = 100.0;
Mat m = ...
Mat thresh = m > th;
```

---

For the other way around, i.e. set to `255` all values `< th`, you can do like:

```
double th = 100.0;
Mat m = ...
Mat thresh;
threshold(m, thresh, th, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV); // <-- using INVerted threshold
```

or:

```
double th = 100.0;
Mat m = ...
Mat thresh = m <= th; // <-- using less-or-equal comparison 

//Mat thresh = m < th; // Will also work, but result will be different from the "threshold" version
```

---

Please note that while `threshold` will produce a result matrix of the same type of the input, the matrix expression will always produce a `CV_8U` result.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since I discovered the [LUT](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20LUT(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20lut,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20interpolation)) function in OpenCV, I've been trying to use it wherever I can. And this looks like a good opportunity.

I assume you're working on a matrix of type `CV_8U` and using OpenCV in a C++ program (it should be easily portable to Python otherwise).

You first have to define a `lookUpTable` like this:

```
cv::Mat lookUpTable(256,1,CV_8U);
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if(i < 50)
        lookUpTable.at<uchar>(i,0) = 50;
    else
        lookUpTable.at<uchar>(i,0) = i;
}
```

This means that every value in the matrix below fifty will be brought to 50.

Then, the only thing left to do is this:

```
cv::Mat image;  # your original image
cv::Mat thresholdedImage;
cv::LUT(image, lookUpTable, thresholdedImage);
```

And here you go.

There may be more efficient solutions, or maybe I'm doing something unnecessarily complicated but I find it elegant.

Comment: I´m using CV_32F. So actually I can not acess it via uchar because most of my pixels are float, right?

Comment: Oh yes. Then my solution is really not adapted for you, I'm afraid. You can  still try to use OpenCv threshold function on `1.0 - originalImage` with adapted thresholds

Comment: Actually I can not use the OpenCV threshold function, because there I can not check for smaller than. Or do i think wrong?

Comment: You can use threshold to bring smaller values to zero. which is not exactly what you want.

However, checking for greater values on `1.0 - originalImage` is the same as checking for smaller on `originalImage`