# Convert image to black and white (not grayscale) using OpenCV iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, filter

I have gone through many of similar question here on SO, but it does not give the specific output that i need. I have tried converting image to black and white but due to some reason some of the text does not appear clear or we can say gets distorted. Below here is the code that i have tried so far...

```
   +(UIImage *)grayImage:(UIImage *)processedImage{

        cv::Mat grayImage = [MMOpenCVHelper cvMatGrayFromAdjustedUIImage:processedImage];

        cv::adaptiveThreshold(grayImage, grayImage, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2);

        cv::GaussianBlur(grayImage, grayImage, cv::Size(1,1), 50.0);

        UIImage *grayeditImage=[MMOpenCVHelper UIImageFromCVMat:grayImage];
        grayImage.release();

        return grayeditImage;

    }

+ (cv::Mat)cvMatGrayFromAdjustedUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
    cv::Mat cvMat = [self cvMatFromAdjustedUIImage:image];
    cv::Mat grayMat;
    if ( cvMat.channels() == 1 ) {
        grayMat = cvMat;
    }
    else {
        grayMat = cv :: Mat( cvMat.rows,cvMat.cols, CV_8UC1 );
        cv::cvtColor( cvMat, grayMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    }
    return grayMat; }

+ (cv::Mat)cvMatFromAdjustedUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to backing data
                                                    cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                    rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                    8,                          // Bits per component
                                                    cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    return cvMat; }

+ (UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
        bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;

    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | (
                                                   cvMat.elemSize() == 3? kCGImageAlphaNone : kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
                                                   );
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                 //width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                 //height
                                        8,                                          //bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                       //bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                            //bytesPerRow
                                        colorSpace,                                 //colorspace
                                        bitmapInfo,// bitmap info
                                        provider,                                   //CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                       //decode
                                        false,                                      //should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault                   //intent
                                        );



    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return finalImage; }
```

The output that i got from the above code is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpBMM.jpg), and the result that i want is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeNld.jpg), any help will be great..! Thank You

**EDITED** :- Original Image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elHhn.jpg)

Comment: Please, add the original input image.

Comment: please check edited question @DanMašek

Comment: Use cv::threshold function.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762959/proper-thresholding-function-in-opencv-c

Comment: Tried..does not work gives more distorted output..@SagarPatel

Comment: @Zღk found any solution ?

Comment: Yes @Nitesh, not upto that mark but pretty much close to that

Comment: @Zღk can you please share the code? Also ur using Swift ?

Comment: @Nitesh i have added code below, and i have not use swift for this

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer my question as i might get helpful. I got B/W output by change in adaptive threshold algorithm and value of block size, below is the code that is used

```
    +(UIImage *)grayImage:(UIImage *)processedImage{ // B/W

    cv::Mat grayImage = [MMOpenCVHelper cvMatGrayFromAdjustedUIImage:processedImage];
    cv::adaptiveThreshold(grayImage, grayImage, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 11, 7);
    cv::GaussianBlur(grayImage, grayImage, cv::Size(1,1), 50.0);

    UIImage *grayeditImage=[MMOpenCVHelper UIImageFromCVMat:grayImage];
    grayImage.release();

    return grayeditImage;
}
```